# HTACCESS 301 redirect to solve redirect error in google search console

Tags: .htaccess, url, search, seo

I have an issue with a 301 redirect in my htaccess file

Now Google search console has a problem with the URLs of my site having a redirect error hence they are not getting indexed.

My htaccess file has the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^car-shows/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/?|)$ /index.php?link1=show-event&eid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

when I go to the URL /car-shows/event-name-1, the URL is changed to the non friendly URL. Is there a way to keep the SEO friendly url and also perform a 301 redirect so that I can solve the proble with google?

Many Thanks

Danny

Comment: Kindly post which URL you want to redirect with which URL.

Comment: _“when I go to the URL /car-shows/event-name-1, the URL is changed to the non friendly URL.”_ - which is not what you want in the first place, because you’re effectively “nullifying” your pretty URLs with that. A `R=301` on _that_ redirect makes _zero_ sense to begin with.

Comment: _“Is there a way to keep the SEO friendly url and also perform a 301 redirect so that I can solve the proble with google?”_ - it is very much unclear as of now, what your problem with Google actually is - your description of that is way too vague. I guess it _might_ be a problem that resulted from doing that nonsense redirect in the first place - but if not, then you need to give us a proper problem description first of all.

Comment: This is the URL that google states there is a redirect error and it doesn't index it

https://cartorque.co/car-shows/officer-cricket-club-fundraiser-show-and-shine-for-beyond-blue-foundation-vic-2182

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.